# Request to be able to delete tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I made a typo while proposing a synonym for the [gtk+] tag and ended up with [gtkgtk2]. Nobody has voted on it. This is a feature request for the proposer of a tag synonym to be able to retract that proposal if nobody has voted on it yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I definitely think this should be implemented.

Typos are one thing, where it's obvious you made a mistake (it doesn't stop people from upvoting, though).

However, it's the situations where you mistakenly create a proposal that is close but incorrect, or end up with a `[tag1]` --> `[tag2]` --> `[tag3]` (or similar) heirarchy, which is obviously not good.

This seems like a really simple thing to implement, and it would allow the community to better manage itself instead of having to ask for help.