# Tag synonym UI faulty and user-unfriendly when Unicode characters are entered

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability, tag-synonyms

I just discovered the “synonyms” feature at the bottom of the info page for a tag, specifically the “c#” tag.

For a laugh, and just to try the feature, I entered “c♯”. This is the Unicode Character “MUSIC SHARP SIGN” (U+266F). Now I recognise that StackOverflow might not want to complicate everything by allowing such outlandish characters, but **the point of my report here is that the user experience was very bad:**

- The system *silently* changed *c♯* into just *c* and went ahead adding the suggestion. It should instead display an error.
- It doesn’t let me downvote or retract the suggestion (which of course wasn’t meant to be just *c*). It should let me remove it in case of mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I've been harping on these UI issues (*especially* silently transforming user input), and yet the dev team doesn't seem to listen. For example, see my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56685/tag-synonyms-the-user-experience/56690#56690).

In Joel's most [recent blog entry](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/08/19.html), he posted a video about UI simplicity. He made the example that while a UI should be as simple as possible for the most likely workflow, if the user makes a mistake or deviates from that workflow, the user *must* be able to undo the action. (This was an *excellent* video, by the way. If you're at all interested in UI design, give it a watch.)

So in this specific case, it's probably easiest to simply reject the input if the transformed input doesn't match the original input (after some processing, such as removing whitespace). I also think that a user should be able to rescind a tag synonym proposal without waiting for downvotes to blow it away. This minimizes moderator and support overhead in the case of a mistake. (The latter feature request is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61337/request-to-be-able-to-delete-tag-synonyms).)