# Retract synonym suggestion

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request to be able to delete tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61337/request-to-be-able-to-delete-tag-synonyms)

You should be able to retract a synonym you suggested, perhaps only within a certain time frame or if it has a score <= 0.

For example, "someone" might have [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linker/synonyms) [link] be synonymed with [linker]—forgetting hypertext links—immediately realized their mistake, and not be able to do anything about it.  (Please downvote that synonym for me.)

(On a side note, [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/link) needs cleaned up to have many retagged to [linker].)

Comment: +1 I agree with this. Would be nice to back out.

Comment: While the titling is different, this is basically the same request as [Request to be able to delete tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61337/request-to-be-able-to-delete-tag-synonyms), which is asking for the ability to retract a mistakenly proposed synonym rather than have to wait for it to get downvoted.

Comment: @Grace: Thanks for finding the duplicate.