# Deleting a self-suggested tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

So, I suggested a tag synonym for a tag. But the more I thought about it, the more I realized that the tag synonym I suggested was not correct and I want to remove it. However the tag (both the master tag and the synonym) are relatively new so I don't have the "necessary score" to delete or at least vote to delete that tag synonym. No one does.

The master tag has about 5 questions on it already, but the synonym is really unnecessary and I feel it just causes more confusion than anything.

So I was wondering if there's a way I could request a moderator to delete it for me? Or some other method? Is there an expiration on stale (non-voted upon) tag synonyms?

If a moderator can indeed delete a tag-synonym, I will edit my question with the synonym to delete.

EDIT:

The tag-synonym I wish to have deleted is:

[kynetx](/questions/tagged/kynetx)

I suggested it as a synonym for the master tag, [krl](/questions/tagged/krl). But then thought about it more and realized that [kynetx](/questions/tagged/kynetx) is a meta tag and cannot stand on its own and ***is not*** a synonym for krl, (Kynetx Rule Language). Furthermore, I can't think of any stackoverflow-appropriate (ie, non-subjective, specific answerable question), where [kynetx](/questions/tagged/kynetx) could be used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the official feature request for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61337/request-to-be-able-to-delete-tag-synonyms

Comment: I believe a mod can nuke them immediately. If you post it here regardless, there will probably be enough drive-bys on Meta to help you out even if a mod doesn't see it.