# Take into account the score in both tags to allow tag synonym suggestions

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Yesterday I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) **initialization-list** as a synonym of **ctor-initializer**. But this was my very first tag synonym suggestion, and I got it wrong - What I really meant to suggest was the other way round: **ctor-initializer** is a synonym of **initialization-list**.

However, I *don't* have the needed score 5 to suggest the inverse synonym, which is the one I really like.

I actually don't like the abbreviated tag **ctor-initializer** in the first place - I'd prefer **constructor-initializer**, but that would be just a retag request.

I'd like to be able to:

1. Delete my own tag synonym suggestions (A [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71315/deleting-a-self-suggested-tag-synonym) suggestion, actually)
2. Be allowed to suggest tag synonyms in *either* sense if my *total* score in both tags is at least 5.

In the meantime, please reject my suggestion :)